# Java: good programming approach?

Tags: java, oop

I am being asked to learn Java very quickly and I am struggling with not only the verbose syntax but also the expected style and approach requirements.

Given a simple FizzBuzz challenge I produced the following code:

```
public class FizzBuzz {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean hit;

    for (int n = 1; n <= 30; n++) {

        hit = false;

        if (n % 3 == 0) {
            System.out.print("Fizz");
            hit = true;
        }
        if (n % 5 == 0) {
            System.out.print("Buzz");
            hit = true;
        }
        if (hit != true) {
            System.out.print(n);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Asked to refactor this code by the lead programmer and to consider possible future requirements and code managability issues I gave it some thought and produced the following refactored code:

```
public class FizzBuzz {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean hit;

    for (int n = 1; n < 30; n++) {

        hit = false;

        hit =  (n % 3 == 0) ? writeAction("Fizz") : hit;
        hit =  (n % 5 == 0) ? writeAction("Buzz") : hit;

        if ( ! hit)
           System.out.print(n);
        System.out.println();
    }
  }
   private static boolean writeAction(String actionWord){
     System.out.print(actionWord);
   return true;
   }
}
```

However, the guy who set this task has moved on quite quickly and I never got any feedback on this approach. Am I going in the right direction with this or have I regressed?. To me this should scale better and would be easier to modify. I have also considered that maybe he was expecting some sort of TDD approach? I am aware that I have no tests currently.

Comment: Try moving the if checks to a separate method.  For the first two if checks try using the same method with 2 arguments (the divisor and the "actionWord" as you called it)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking to *review* **working** code belong on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site isn't for reviews, but in case your question gets moved, here is some feedback (from the "clean code" perspective):

- your "main" code sits in a `main()` method. Makes re-using it very hard.
- talking about re-use - various things in there prevent re-using it
- you have some duplicated code in there
- you are violating the single layer of abstraction principle

How I would write something along the lines of:

```
public class FizzBuzz {

    private final OutputStream out;

    public FizzBuzz(OutputStream out) {
      this.out = out;
    }

    public void runFizzBuzzUpTo(int n) {
      for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if ( writeIfTrue(n % 3 == 0, "Fizz") ) { 
          continue;
        }
        if ( writeIfTrue(n % 5 == 0, "Buzz") ) { 
          continue;
        }
        out.println(n);
      }
    }

    private boolean writeIfTrue(boolean toCheck, String word) {
      if (toCheck) {
        out.println(word);
      }
      return toCheck;
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     new FizzBuzz(System.out).runFizzBuzzUpto(30);
   }
}
```

Things I changed:

- made the output the "core" thing of a class
- provided the possibility to run for arbitrary positive numbers

Stuff still missing:

- "single layere of abstraction" is still not good
- instead of fixing "30" in main() - one could check for exactly one argument passed to main() - which would then be used as parameter for `runFizzBuzzUpTo()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Lots of food for thought there. Apologies as I realise now that my question was not really suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the second code is more modular and easier to modify that way. I mostly don't prefer to write the if conditions in the short way... 
The method writeAction could be void because you don't have to return anything. 
But you have good ideas :)